# Wrap in a shortcode a function and then return and echo the result in my editor on my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, editor

Here's my problem:

Two weeks ago I created a nice function to populate my options in a select element for a wordpress website. My purpose was to add all the names of my members with their emails as values from some posts that I create under the category "Member", so, whenever I edit, add or delete any member in my website, that section will be automatically updated.

Something like:

```
<select>
<option value="myemail@test.com">First user</option>
<option value="myemail2@test.com">Second user</option>
<option value="myemail3@test.com">Third user</option>
</select>
```

To achieve my goal I modify the loop in this way:

```
$members = [];
$temp_query = $wp_query;
query_posts("cat=2&showposts=20");
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$membername = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'name', true );
$memberemail = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'email', true );
if ( ! empty( $membername ) ) {
    $members[] = '<option value="' . $memberemail . '">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', true) .'</option>';
}
endwhile;
```

and then I call the options in my selector like that:

```
<select class="drops" name="smallsan">
    <?php echo implode($members); ?>
</select>
```

So far so good except for the fact that I wrap this code in my template.

My problem is that I need to run a plugin in order to hide the page from people who are not subscribed so I have to add the html in the loop in the editor and I can't execute php there.

So I tried to wrap the code in my function.php to associate it with a shortcode like that:

```
function mymembershortcode() {
    $members = [];
    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    query_posts("cat=2&showposts=20");
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $membername = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'name', true );
    $memberemail = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'email', true );
    if ( ! empty( $membername ) ) {
        $members[] = '<option value="' . $memberemail . '">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', true) .'</option>';
    }
    endwhile;
    return implode($members);
}
add_shortcode('mymemberselector', 'mymembershortcode');
```

To run the shortcode:

```
<select class="drops" name="smallsan">
    [mymemberselector]
</select>
```

essentially whenever I need but, it doesn't work, and I suspect it is because I can't return and echo at the same time.

Does anyone know how can I solve my problem?

Comment: you're returning the implode of members but not echoing anything. change that return to an echo and then return normally to continue execution

Comment: So I should do something like:
echo implode($members);
return;

Comment: @LordNeo that's how shortcodes work. They're supposed to return, not echo.

Comment: @WheatBeak shorcodes are like php functions, they are called to do something not explicitly to print/echo something, so if your function doesn't echo anything it won't display anything. check the post title shortcode for example.

Comment: @LordNeo from the WordPress Codex: `"Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce output of any kind."`  More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode#Notes

Comment: @WheatBeak you're right, i didn't bothered to check if the behaviour changed since i used WP. You can still tho return the html format using ob_start and returnning the ob_get_clean

Comment: Yes briefly it's not working because.. but where's my mistake? Is it any other way to retrieve that result? It is working on the page so I assume that I can create a function and I can use it anywhere but I need to run the write and run the function in my editor as a post (so I need to interact with the editor of wordpress). I'm very naive on how it works the function.php and how to retrieve something outside a custom template where I can work directly with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function mymembershortcode() {
    $members = [];
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'cat' => 2,
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
    )); 

    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        $membername = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name', true );
        $memberemail = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'email', true );
        if ( ! empty( $membername ) ) {
            $members[] = '<option value="' . $memberemail . '">' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'name', true) .'</option>';
        }

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    return implode($members);

}

add_shortcode('mymemberselector', 'mymembershortcode');
```

Here's some info about why you should NEVER use `query_posts()`
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: Strange,  and what happens if you try my code in your template in place of where yours was working?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I was using `the_ID()` which echoes, instead of `get_the_ID()`,  it's late in the day,  brain fart :P

Comment: I can try but my biggest problem is that I can't use a template since I'm running a plugin on top of the page to hide the page if you're not member. You can see the behavior of the page at the link that I've just sent you

Comment: I'll try with the update! don't worry same issue, it's been a long day

Comment: Awesome,  just don't forget to read the link about why you shouldn't use `query_posts()` :P

Comment: Also, I've got another question for you. Is it a good habit to put every shortcode in the function.php file?

Comment: If you have a lot of them just for organization's sake it'd be good to put them in a `shortcodes.php` and then just include it in your `functions.php`